# html - how to send to email both - select tag value and input value?

Tags: html, forms, send

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form action="" method="post" enctype="text/plain">
IP Address:<br>
<input type="text" name="" placeholder=""><br>
Port:<br>
<input type="text" name="" placeholder=""><br>
Game:<br>
<input type="text" name="" placeholder="" ><br>
Type:<br>
<input type="option" name="Type" size="50"><br><br>
<select name="cars">
    <option value="volvo">Volvo XC90</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab 95</option>
    <option value="mercedes">Mercedes SLK</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi TT</option>
  </select>

<input type="submit" value="Send">
<input type="reset" value="Reset">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to send this to mail when I write the right action="mailto:....." I can send only the input things, but not select tag selected option i tried any of this things separately it works but when i wanna do this with one button it doesn't works...

Comment: Do you have actual mail sending code, or just the HTML form? Because this doesn't really do anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use in your HTML somthing like this :

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>

<input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" id="Email"><br>
<input type="text" name="titre" placeholder="Title" id="Title"><br>
<textarea name="content" placeholder="Content" id="Content"></textarea><br>
<button id="send">send</button>
```

Now using jquery add this :

```
$("#send").click(function(){
   var email=$('#Email').val();
   var title=$('#Title').val();
   var content=$('#Content').val();
   document.location.href = "mailto:"+email+"?subject="+title+"&body="+content;
});
```

for the options tag in your select you have to know that you can only send the selected value from options inside the select tag

hope this will help you.

Comment: Yes it works but i wanna make a auto sending email I mean I will set an email to go the form there but i cant get the options value i know i can get only selected but what is the way to do that ?

Comment: When you make a form you have to put your url in action example: action="index.php", but i didn't understand what you really want to do;

Comment: in my previous answer you can select all the values from all inputs and select tags and put in the url all the values needed ex: document.location.href="mailto:"+email+"subject="+title+"&body="+content; where content is a string containing all the values you want to send

Comment: I am sorry, I want to send a input value and option value to email, example :
Favourite car ?
1. Volvo(option)
2. Bmw(option)
3. Mercedes(option)
Horse power:
|____________|(input)

I want this info to come on my email but i tried to send it but only input are going to my email, options didn't go there

Comment: I tried only option to send and it was done, i tried only input and it was done, but how to send both of them with one form and one submit button ?